# Set input model value based on operator logic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want my input only accept and update the new scope value if a logical operation passes, e.g.:

```
<input id="priceRangeMin" type="text" ng-model="minPrice">
<input id="priceRangeMax" type="text" ng-model="maxPrice">
```

If a user enters a `minPrice` which is greater than the `maxPrice`, it should retain the old value.
Is it possible to achieve this on the *view* level?

*Note*: I don't want to use `<input type="number">`.

Comment: what do you mean by 'on the view level'?

Comment: Well, I'd rather not use any watchers, filters or service to deal with that trivial kind of validation. I was just wondering if there is something to just compare two scope variables within the view or template by logical operators before setting the new value.

Comment: how about using a directive?

Comment: Yes, a directive would be as possible as a service here, but I am searching for a way to compare the new value **before** it will be processed by other components.

Comment: You do need a listener to check changes in this element. If you want to keep angularJS from starting new $digest loops, you might even consider solving your problem "outside angularJS"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plausible Scenario where you "watch" an element without a watcher/eventListener.
However, if you want to go easy on angularJS, you can solve this outside angular, and still define the logic in a directive.

you could define a yourprefix-not-higher-than directive that accepts another input id (*not the ng-model since we do watch outside angular here*).
Example HTML/AngularJS View:

```
<input id="priceRangeMin" type="text" ng-model="minPrice" foo-not-higher-than="priceRangeMax">
<input id="priceRangeMax" type="text" ng-model="maxPrice">
```

Now in your directive you add a simple jQuery event listener on the HTML element itself. If it changes, you check back with the refferenced element (in our example it is priceRangeMax).

```
...
link: function(scope, elem, attributes) {
  var refferencedAttribute = $window.jQuery('#'.attributes.fooNotHigherThan);
  $window.jQuery(elem).on('change', function() {
    if(refferencedAttribute < $window.jQuery(elem).val()) {
      // you're able to do this right?
    }
  }
...
```

However, treating AngularJS like a princess may not be the right approach. Binding the view to the scope requires watcher naturally and having one more to esatblish your logic sure won't kill any browser.

So you might as well use AngularJS in your directive, refferencing the model rather than the HTML DOM Element. You might end up with a faster solution that way.